# Varnish + nginx 503 error backend fetch failed

Tags: nginx, varnish, 503-error

some assistance would be appreciated. My setup:
LB -> VARNISH -> NGINX

For reasons unknown, I started getting random error 503 on the clients. I've checked the logs on varnish and Nginx...

Varnish:
In the logs I see the client request, with RespStatus 503, ResReason Backend fetch failed.

Nginx:
If I search for the same client request in Nginx logs I don't see it.

I'd guess the issue should be on the Nginx server part? I've looked at the network traffic/CPU/memory etc...and nothing looks overloaded.

My Nginx conf.:

```
user www-data;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;
pcre_jit on;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 65535;

}

http {

        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        server_tokens off;

        client_max_body_size 1m;

        sendfile on;

        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/nginx/dh2048.pem;

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:2m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1h;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        gzip  on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;

        map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
                default upgrade;
                '' close;
        }
        log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

}
```

varnish:

```
backend server1 { 
  .host = "192.168.245.167";    
  .port = "80";           
  .max_connections = 3000; 

  .first_byte_timeout     = 300s;  
  .connect_timeout        = 10s;    
  .between_bytes_timeout  = 6s;     
}

sub vcl_init {
  # Called when VCL is loaded, before any requests pass through it.
  # Typically used to initialize VMODs.

  new vdir = directors.round_robin();
  vdir.add_backend(server1);
...
```

**EDIT**:

Adding also varnislog output for 1 request:

```
*   << Request  >> 609730940
-   Begin          req 640024598 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1661355668.683547 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1661355668.683547 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       192.168.245.165 40772 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         someurl
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      user-agent: agent
-   ReqHeader      accept-encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      x-real-ip: 172.31.68.46
-   ReqHeader      x-ssl: 1
-   ReqHeader      x-forwarded-for: 172.31.68.46
-   ReqUnset       x-forwarded-for: 172.31.68.46
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 172.31.68.46, 192.168.245.165
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 172.31.68.46, 192.168.245.165
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 172.31.68.46
-   ReqUnset       host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      Host: example.com
-   ReqURL         someurl
-   VCL_return     pass
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       PASS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 609730941 pass
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1661355668.683759 0.000212 0.000212
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2022 15:41:08 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 609730940
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: MISS
-   RespHeader     X-Cache-Hits: 0
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1661355668.683778 0.000231 0.000019
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 286
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1661355668.683838 0.000291 0.000060
-   ReqAcct        429 0 429 286 286 572
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 609730941
--  Begin          bereq 609730940 pass
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1661355668.683670 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       someurl
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    user-agent: agent
--  BereqHeader    accept-encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    x-real-ip: 172.31.68.46
--  BereqHeader    x-ssl: 1
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 172.31.68.46
--  BereqHeader    Host: example.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 609730941
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  FetchError     backend server1: busy
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1661355668.683706 0.000036 0.000036
--  Timestamp      Error: 1661355668.683709 0.000038 0.000002
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2022 15:41:08 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Length         286
--  BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
--  End
```

Any ideas/hints as to what I should look for?

Comment: Please share the full output of a `varnishlog` transaction by calling `varnishlog -g session -q "RespStatus == 503"`. You can add this content to your question. It will explain why the 503 is returned.

Comment: Hi Thijs...I've updated the main question.

Comment: nginx is a caching service. why do you use a second proxy infront of it? it has been already proved by serval sites that vanish slower as nginx.  inside the nginx. conf is nothing from interesting. please provide `nginx -tT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--  FetchError     backend server1: busy` message indicates that Varnish cannot connect to Nginx because Nginx is *busy*. This means that it has reached its max connections limit.

Either increase this limit in Nginx if you believe the server can handle more simultaneous connections, or limit the amount of backend connections Varnish can open to Nginx by lowering the `.max_connections` property in your backend definition.

Limiting max connections in Varnish will not make this problem go away though.

It's important to figure out why Varnish needs to open up so many connections.

- Is the hit rate too low?
- Are there too many requests to uncacheable resources?
- Are there flaws in your VCL that trigger these backend fetches which overload your backend server

I recommend that you read https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/troubleshooting-varnish/#varnish-is-not-caching to learn how to spot uncacheable content. Based on the logs you can make an assessment and maybe take corrective actions in your VCL.

I would also recommend that you read the following tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/. It explains what Varnish caches by default and what is deemed uncacheable. This will help you understand to what extent potential VCL improvements are required.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer. The connection limit was the issue, as I have a lot of files that I don't cache. Also thank you for the links...we'll have a look to see how to improve our conf.

BR,
Robert